# Where can I find the BC heroic keys?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to do all the Burning Crusade Heroics for no special reason, but I need the keys to access them.

I started playing during The Wrath of the Lich King, so I completely missed all the quest lines in the Outlands that lead up to the Heroic dungeons.

Does anyone know where I can find the appropriate quest lines that will get me the keys?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't even try looking for them. :)

Comment: I so dislike it when there's no text inside the question! Fixed!

Comment: @badp at least this time, I actually knew the answer... just thought it'd be a nice addition in here.

Comment: seeding is kind of okay, [just don't overdo it](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-should-we-do-about-excessive-content-seeding).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keys to heroic instances in BC are bought from the vendors for various reputations at Honored rep.

- Thrallmar/Honor Hold for the Hellfire instance.
- Cenarion Expedition for the instances in Coilfang Reservoir
- Lower City for the Auchendoun instances
- Sha'tar for Tempest Keep
- Keepers of Time for the Caverns of Time stuff

and for Magister's Terrace you must complete the quest for it in regular difficulty.
For all the rep based ones it's pretty easy to get enough rep just by question, if not doing one or two regular instances.
A list can be found here.
http://www.wowwiki.com/Instance_attunement

Comment: and thanks for the "instance attunement" link

Answer (score 1):

Each of them requires reputation with the associated faction, then they are purchased from the faction quartermaster.

http://www.wowwiki.com/Key has a list of them.